# JTree: how to get the text of one leaf?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want to get text of an JTree in format:

1. Root
2. Node1
3. leaf1
4. leaf2 <------- click
5. Node2

when I click on the leaf leaves me information in a JPanel

Comment: Add a [`TreeSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionListener.html) to the `JTree`, it will notifiy when the selected node changes and you can extract the details from the event using the [`TreePath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html) from the [`TreeSelectionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionEvent.html).  Take a closer look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel lbl;
    private JTree tree;

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        tree = new JTree();
        tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(getListener());

        lbl = new JLabel("empty");

        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        add(lbl,BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    private TreeSelectionListener getListener() {
        return new TreeSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)  tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                lbl.setText(node == null ? "empty" : node.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

Read more in [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select).